# Unresolved external symbol : __cairo_path_fixed_stroke_to_traps

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, gtk, cairo

I was following this [post](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/Win32/MSVCCompilationOfGTKStack#Cairo) to build and install cairo.

However, I got stuck with the below error :

```
Error   277 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __cairo_path_fixed_stroke_to_traps referenced in function __cairo_traps_compositor_stroke C:\gtk_compilation\cairo\cairo-1.12.18\msvc\vs10\cairo-traps-compositor.obj cairo
```

The installation guide says I need to turn off the whole programme optimization
which I did using the the `/GL-` compiler flag but still there is no way around the issue.

Below is an excerpt from the `C:\gtk_compilation\cairo\cairo-1.12.18\msvc\vs10\cairo-traps-compositor.c` file :

```
cairo_int_status_t (*func) (const cairo_path_fixed_t    *path,
                const cairo_stroke_style_t  *stroke_style,
                const cairo_matrix_t    *ctm,
                const cairo_matrix_t    *ctm_inverse,
                double           tolerance,
                cairo_traps_t       *traps);
composite_traps_info_t info;
unsigned flags;

if (antialias == CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_BEST || antialias == CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_GOOD) {
        func = _cairo_path_fixed_stroke_polygon_to_traps;
        flags = 0;
    } else {
        func = _cairo_path_fixed_stroke_to_traps; /* line#2183 */
        flags = need_bounded_clip (extents) & ~NEED_CLIP_SURFACE;
    }
```

The above  functions are defined in **cairoint.h** as :

```
cairo_private cairo_int_status_t
_cairo_path_fixed_stroke_to_traps (const cairo_path_fixed_t *path,
                   const cairo_stroke_style_t   *stroke_style,
                   const cairo_matrix_t *ctm,
                   const cairo_matrix_t *ctm_inverse,
                   double        tolerance,
                   cairo_traps_t    *traps);

cairo_private cairo_int_status_t
_cairo_path_fixed_stroke_polygon_to_traps (const cairo_path_fixed_t *path,
                       const cairo_stroke_style_t   *stroke_style,
                       const cairo_matrix_t *ctm,
                       const cairo_matrix_t *ctm_inverse,
                       double        tolerance,
                       cairo_traps_t    *traps);
```

Could anybody please suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: cairoint.h isn't where the function is defined; it's where it's declared. The function is defined in cairo-path-stroke-traps.c. Is that file being compiled? Is it being linked?

Comment: Thanks for that, I just found that this particular file is not in the project sources . Gosh, why didn't I check this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @andlabs comment, I found out that the file **cairo-path-stroke-traps.c** was not included in the Visual Studio project sources. Added this one and rebuilt the solution - Voila  !!

Comment: Huh, what distribution of cairo isn't including that file? That'll need to be fixed...

Comment: @andlabs: I downloaded the tarball from the official site and Visual Studio project file from here [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Win32/MSVCCompilationOfGTKStack?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=cairo-vsprojects.zip).There is a chance that, the project file is obsolete, but even then it's hard to miss `cairo-path-stroke-traps.c` IMHO.